# iOS broadcasting live to Azure Media Services

Tags: ios, azure, azure-media-services, videocore

I am trying to make a Periscope-like app (not practically, but technical requirements are alike) where users can start streaming quickly from their iPhone to an unknown amount of users, both mobile. I am trying to use Azure Media Services for live video streaming, but even after reading pages of documentation I'm stuck.

I'm using VideoCore (https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) to publish from iOS device to the RTMP server. On local (using Wowza) I can just connect to the local server with my set username and password as shown:

```
vcSession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720) frameRate:30 bitrate:1000000 useInterfaceOrientation:NO];
[self.view addSubview:vcSession.previewView];
vcSession.previewView.frame = self.view.bounds;
vcSession.delegate = self;
[vcSession startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://172.20.10.2:1935/live?rtmpauth=test:test" andStreamKey:@"test"];
```

Where the `rtmpauth` parameter has the `username:password` format, which I've set both to `test` on my local server. It works. In Azure, I've created a channel named `test`, and I've got the following Ingest URL:

`rtmp://test-myappname.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/some-long-hexadecimal-string`

In Wirecast, I'm able to stream to URL (though EXTREMELY slow and connection frequently lost, don't know why) by selecting Azure Media Services in Output Settings and typing that Ingest URL. In iOS, I have no idea how to connect to Azure Media Services.

In `startRtmpSessionWithURL:andStreamKey:` method, I've tried all the possible combinations of URL and a stream key, but no luck. I have no idea what my username/password is (nothing is given at the Azure side), what the stream key is (I've tried `test`, `live`, empty string) and what that long hexadecimal string is (some sources say that it's called a locator, though).

What is the correct format of RTMP URL and stream key when connecting to Azure Media Services for streaming?

Comment: Are you sure that you are able to stream to RTSP with the  "[vcSession startRtmpSessionWithURL:@"rtmp://172.20.10.2:1935/live?rtmpauth=test:test" andStreamKey:@"test"];" as as perVideocore team they have not implemented the authentication in there code yet?

Comment: Hi Can, Sorry this is a bit of a sidetrack from your question... I'm trying to use VideoCore for a project and can't get it to work. Do you have any reference how you get it configured ?

Comment: @Illuminati hey, I've abandoned this project, but I think the code in the question is pretty much it. where exactly are you stuck at?

Comment: I managed to get the VideoCore working with 2 days messing with different c++ errors. Now it is able to load the camera from the app but it won't transmit anything over RTMP to Azure. I'm about to give up too - Wowza GoCoder SDK seems like a workable option now. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 4):

I'll find someone to help you. I think you are just missing a stream name after the long hex string in the URL.

rtmp://test-myappname.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:1935/live/some-long-hexadecimal-string/**[YOUR-CUSTOM-STREAM-NAME-Anything Really!]**

Also, do you have any control over the encoding settings? Its possible that some encoding settings are not right. We have not tested with that VideoCore library, so it may also be that there is a slight variation in the RTMP protocol (since it is very poorly documented and there is a lot of missing information out there).

I'm curious why your Wirecast setup is having trouble as well. That doesn't sound good to start with. Network issue?  Are you setting it to the proper Encoder preset with H.264 and NOT x264 set?

Review your settings in Wirecast against Cenk's blog post here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/18/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll be looking at the URL issue. For VideoCore, I know that some people use it successfully with RTMP servers, including myself (local/Wowza setup). And yes, I've checked the encoder it's H.264 (which is Azure's default preset on Wirecast).

Comment: Hi john , do you have any update on this. I'm having the same issue with VideoCore and Azure RTMP and can't quite get it to work.